# Does a Psychic with the Improved Eldritch Heritage feat for the Psychic Bloodline get any benefit from Undercasting Prodigy?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, spellcasting, psychic-class, occult-magic

Does a [Psychic](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/occult-adventures/occult-classes/psychic/) with the [Improved Eldritch Heritage](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/improved-eldritch-heritage) feat for the [Psychic Bloodline](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/bloodlines/bloodlines-from-paizo/psychic-sorcerer-bloodline/) get any benefit from [Undercasting Prodigy](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/bloodlines/bloodlines-from-paizo/psychic-sorcerer-bloodline/#Undercasting_Prodigy_Sp)?

Undercasting Prodigy says:

> Starting at 9th level, whenever you gain a new level of spells, you
>   automatically replace any psychic bloodline spells that can be
>   undercast with the highest-level version you can cast in your list of
>   spells known. For example, at 9th level, you would replace mind thrust
>   I, id insinuation I, and ego whip I with mind thrust IV, id
>   insinuation III, and ego whip II, respectively, as spells known.

If a psychic knows the bloodline spells from choosing them as a psychic and not from the bloodline, can they still replace lower level spells with higher level spells when able?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because the Bloodline spells are a specific class feature of a sorcerer class. The spells in your psychic spells known list are not bloodline spells even if they appear on that list.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! You can improve this answer by citing/quoting the rules which are the basis for you answer. Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: @Someone_Evil I am not sure what to cite. Sorcerer page?

Comment: You could quote the feature where bloodline spells are introduced/defined, and point out where/how your psychic spells are defined differently.